# Obter o usuário logado no Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Bom dia, pessoal.

Tenho uma aplicação pequena feita totalmente em Django Admin e estou precisando obter o usuário logado para fazer uma consulta específica de listagem de clientes cadastrados e e outros modelos por este usuário/empresa específico de modo a separar a aplicação por grupo de usuários.

Como é que posso fazer isso com o Django Admin? Porque pelo que li por aí o `request` e o `instance` só funcionam nas views e como estou usando apenas o Django Admin como CRUD não utilizo views.

Tentei colocar o request dentro do `models.Manager` e recebo uma exceção:

```
class ClienteManager(models.Manager):
def get_queryset(self, request):
    return super(ClienteManager, self).get_queryset().filter(cliente=True).filter(escritorio=request.user.username)

TypeError at /admin/cadastro/cliente/
get_queryset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Olá Alison,**

Sua pergunta é bem ampla, mas vamos ver se te ajudo:
O Django Admin vem com varias ferramentas desabilitadas, você terá que habilita-las conforme sua necessidade.
O comando que necessitas será para lista é '`list.display`' mas se for para fazer uma pesquisa ,porque olhei você usando o `queryset`, é o '`search_fields`'.
Você usará este comando na app '`admin.py`'

> ModelAdmin.get_search_fields(request)
>
> The get_search_fields method is given the HttpRequest and is expected to return the same kind of sequence type as for the
>   search_fields attribute.

```
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['date_created']
    search_fields = ['question_text']
```

> ModelAdmin.list_display
>
> Set list_display to control which fields are displayed on the change
>   list page of the admin.
>
> Example:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name')
```

Exemplos de ferramentas e seus comandos do Django admin:
[image: Exemplos de ferramentas do Django Admin]

**Extra:**
O Django admin tem vários modelos pré estabelecidos, como reset de senha e outros, caso você queira sobrescrever algum modelo, como mudar cor, você terá que descobrir qual o nome da *view* na raiz, existe dois meios para edita-la, primeiro editar na raiz(problema) e segundo criar uma view com o mesmo nome na sua `urls.py.`. Mas isso é outra história.

**Fonte:**

Coisas que Você deve saber sobre Django Admin para seu App seja Grande

[Medium: Things You Must Know About Django Admin As Your App Gets Bigger](https://medium.com/@hakibenita/things-you-must-know-about-django-admin-as-your-app-gets-bigger-6be0b0ee9614)

Documentação do Dajngo especifica do assunto:

[Django Admin Site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/)

**Espero que tenha ajudado , e que a força esteja com você.**

Answer (score 0):

Opa amigo. Então, o que eu queria, na verdade, era filtrar registros por usuário logado de modo a dividir a aplicação para mais de um usuário fazendo com que um não veja o registro do outro.

Eu consegui fazer esse filtro com o seguinte código:

```
# Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574788/filter-django-admin-by-logged-in-user
class FilterUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        form.cleaned_data['escritorio'] = request.user.id
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            qs = super(FilterUserAdmin, self).get_queryset(request) 
            return qs.filter(escritorio__user=request.user)
        else:
            qs = super(FilterUserAdmin, self).get_queryset(request) 
            return qs.all()

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            # the changelist itself
            return True
        return obj.escritorio.user == request.user
```

Ficou funcionando como eu queria, só que agora me deparei com outro problema que ainda estou tentando resolver que é fazer esse filtro funcionar também nos formulários que possuem chaves estrangeiras porque percebi que o filtro funciona belezinha nos formulário sem chave estrangeira, mas quando tem algum campo estrangeiro ele carrega todos os registros de dentro do banco.